# How does Swift Array support valid Element subtype assignment?

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, casting, containers

I want to cast or assign a custom Swift Container Type to a "compatible" declared variable container-type like native Swift Array supports. The code below is a complete example with the problem identified.
Array supports it, my custom struct does not.

I have examined the interface for Swift.Collection.Array,and have begun checking the source code. Somehow Array supports the line below:
`let array3: Array<HasHeading> = array2`
while my custom type ThingContainer does NOT support the same semantics
`let things3: ThingContainer<HasHeading> = things1`

```swift
protocol HasHeading {
    var heading: Double { get }
}

struct Heading: HasHeading {
    let heading: Double
}

let heading1 = Heading(heading: 89.0)
let heading2 = Heading(heading: 90.0)


struct ThingContainer<T> {
    let thingOne: T
    let thingTwo: T

    init(thingOne: T, thingTwo: T) {
        self.thingOne = thingOne
        self.thingTwo = thingTwo
    }
}

let things1: ThingContainer<Heading> = ThingContainer(thingOne: heading1,
                                                      thingTwo: heading2)

let things2: ThingContainer<HasHeading> = ThingContainer(thingOne: heading1,
                                                         thingTwo: heading2)
//error: cannot convert value of type 'ThingContainer<Heading>' to specified type 'ThingContainer<HasHeading>'
let things3: ThingContainer<HasHeading> = things1
let things4: ThingContainer<HasHeading> = things2

let array1: Array<Heading> = [heading1,heading2]

let array2: Array<HasHeading> = [heading1,heading2]

let array3: Array<HasHeading> = array1
let array4: Array<HasHeading> = array2
```

How does Swift native Array type support:
`let array3: Array<HasHeading> = array1`
I cannot have anything to do with the contained type.
Is this a form of automatic bridging?

Comment: try `let things3: ThingContainer<HasHeading> = ThingContainer(thingOne: things1.thingOne, thingTwo: things1.thingTwo)`

Comment: See my book http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_explicit_specialization and scroll down to the box that says "Generics Are Not Covariant". Array can do this but you can't. :(

Comment: Also see this famous article https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/type-variance-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called generic covariance, and unfortunately, Swift doesn't support it. Compiler magic hard-codes covariance for a small set of types, like standard library collections and `Optional<T>`.

For more information on the subject, I suggest reading [Friday Q&A 2015-11-20: Covariance and Contravariance
by Mike Ash](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html)